# How to check if either none or all textboxes in a page have text entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am developing one website in php with ajax, javascript and jquery.

In one form there is a dynamic number of textboxes depending upon the user's status. The textbox id will be 'tb'+id like tb1,tb5,tb25,tb60 etc. and all textbox class is 'po'.

Now on the click of a save button i need to validate these 'tb' textboxes. 
Either all textboxes should be blank or none of them.

can anyone help me to achieve this please??

Comment: Get the state of the first textbox. Then loop through the rest, and if any of them have a different state than the first one, report a validation failure and exit the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var $pos = $('.po');
var entered = $po.filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.value) == '';
});

if(entered.length != 0 && $pos.length != entered.length){
    //invalid since some are left blank
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var txt_box_count  = $(".po").length;

var empty_text_boxe_count = $(".po").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
}).length;


if(empty_text_box_count == 0)
{
     alert("all text fields are filled");   
}
else if(txt_box_count == empty_text_boxe_count)
{
     alert("all text fields are empty");
}
```

Comment: It is working and helped me. Thanks a lot Kanishka.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var isValid = $('.po').filter(function(){ return !$(this).text();});

if(isValid.length){ /* or if(isValid[0]){
    //some textbox is empty
}
else{
    //all are filled
}
```

Comment: I got a syntax error in first line.

Comment: @Mausami I updated. Check now.

Comment: But its going to if condition everytime.

Comment: @Mausami I updated again. Now this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
        var tLength = $('.po').length;
        var allEmpty = $('.po').filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0;
        });
        var allFilled = $('.po').filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0;
        });

        if (allEmpty == tLength) {
            //All empty
        }
        else if (allFilled == tLength) {
            //All Filled
        }
```